# Does jQuery remove() command work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have a rendered HTML which (partly) looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        sds
    </td>
    <td>
        2014-03-23
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="jsDelete" data-id="1035">Delete</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        hgfg
    </td>
    <td>
        2014-03-23
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="jsDelete" data-id="1037">Delete</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        gfgh
    </td>
    <td>
        2014-03-23
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="jsDelete" data-id="1038">Delete</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And I have a javascript which looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.jsDelete').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/MemberJoinDate/FindUser",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { term: $(this).attr('data-id') },
        success: function (data) {
            bootbox.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete user ' + data.CocUserName + '?',
                function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/MemberJoinDate/JsDelete",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: { id: data.Id },
                            success: function (delData) {
                                $('tr td div[data-id="' + delData.model.Id + '"').parent().parent().remove();
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                alert(xhr.status);
                                alert(thrownError);
                            }

                    });
                    }
                });
        }
    });
    return false; // prevent default
});
});
```

When clicking on Delete in Firefox, Internet Explorer and Google Chrome it works like a charm, but when doing the same in Safari (5.1.7) it does not work!

What happens is that the line $('tr td div[data-id="' + delData.model.Id + '"').parent().parent().remove(); is actually called but nothing happens in Safari (well, the server has responded and deleted what it should, it is only the browser that does not delete the element).

I have even tried changing the line into:

```
var elm = $('tr td div[data-id="' + delData.model.Id + '"').parent().parent();
alert(elm.length);
elm.remove();
```

It does show "1" in the alert box, but it does not remove any objects at all in Safari.

Any hints?

Comment: In a general sense yes, `.remove()` works in Safari. Your selector is missing a closing `]`, so is theoretically wrong in all browsers. It seems weird that `elm.length` could be 1 and yet `.remove()` wouldn't remove whichever element that is.

Comment: Of course nnnnnn! Dough!!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('[data-id="' + delData.model.Id + '"]').parents('tr').remove();
```

Try this, you have an error in your sintaxis "]" missing.